# Relation between Donaldson invariants and GW invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, invariant-theory, string-theory

What is known about the relation of Donaldson invariants on a complex surface $\Sigma$ and GW invariants (or equivalent) of local Calabi-Yau 3folds such as the canonical bundle of $\Sigma$? (if any of course)

I would like to understand any such relation either from a **physics** or a **maths** point of view.

Are there any known relations, results, formulae, papers? Any kind of references would be very much appreciated.

Comment: At least physically, Donaldson is doing a 4d field theory with source $\Sigma$ while GW is doing a 2d field theory with target $\Sigma$.

Comment: Thanks, that is quite incorrect. $\Sigma$ for Donaldson has to be a 4 manifold while for GW (at least in the classical sense) has to be a 3fold. The connection should somehow arise from M-theory construction as $\mathbb{R} \times M_4 \times CY_3$.

Comment: No, need to be M-theory, just leave it as topological string. But I'm drawing distinction between string/M theories and ordinary field theories because of world/brane-sheet formalism. Also, yes forgot to make the target a 3-fold.

Comment: Target does not necessarily need to be 3-fold. For M5 brane 6d (2,0) theory though I think it does. This is where upon proper constructions one can relate Nekrasov part. function on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and GW with target the 3fold with time direction remaining. I cannot find any reference for this story though.

Comment: Let's form a chat to discuss separately. See on chat.stackexchange.com with title this question.

Comment: Hi, I just saw this comment. Sure, I am up for a chat although I have not used it before.

Comment: @AHusain I actually cannot find the chat you mentioned. If you see this message please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Linked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55864/relation-between-donaldson-invariants-and-gw-invariants)